# How to programmatically know if tablet is orizontal or vertical in windows 8 app

Tags: windows-runtime, orientation, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a win8 / winrt xaml app. In my app I need to know if the orientation of the tablet is vertical or horizzontal..
Where can I find this information? I tried to use ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties but without any success.
I try to take a look at:

```
Frame
Application
Window
```

But I can't find what I'm looking for!

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static property `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value` will return the following values.

- FullScreenLandscape
- Filled
- Snapped
- FullScreenPortrait

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since the ApplicationView.Value is deprecated in Windows 8.1, I'd recommend not using that for your app now.  DisplayProperties provides some data here in their API.  Also, depending on your scenario you may not want to think only about the device orientation but the Window size itself that your app is in.  In Win8.1 since you can have 50/50 split, your app may be in a "taller than wider" viewport which effectively is a portrait view as well.

If your app relies on knowing portrait to make assumptions about edges of the physical device, then that is different, but consider looking at Window size and determining if "taller than wider" is a good indication for your app and use that to trigger any changes.

Comment: The problem is that when I try on simulator my components has the same Width and Height even if I'm in portrait mode... Width is always 1366, Height 768